# Qt Compilation Error qeventloop.h

Tags: c++, qt

i have strange compilation error in qeventloop.h header file

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE


class QEventLoopPrivate;

class Q_CORE_EXPORT QEventLoop
{
    Q_GADGET//here I'm getting /home/bs/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore//qeventloop.h:52: error: expected '}' before end of line
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QEventLoop)
```

can anyone help with resolving this problem?

Comment: explain the context, what are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this are often caused by something wrong *before* the `#include` line, usually in the previous include file, or an include file included from it. Most commonly it might be a missing `;` or a mismatched `{` / `}`.

If you can't spot the error by just looking at the previous lines and include files, you could try asking your compiler to save the intermediate files (use [`--save-temps`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps) or [`--save-temps=obj`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps_003dobj) with *gcc*, for example).